# Closure Compiler replaces < with \x3c

Tags: javascript, java, google-closure-compiler

I want to integrate the closure compiler into a large java application.

I have a problem. The closure compiler replaces the `<` with `\x3c` and `>` with `\x3e`

The script I'm trying to compile is

```
$('#something').append($('<div></div>').text('hi'));
```

and closure compiler returns

```
$("#something").append($("\x3cdiv\x3e\x3c/div\x3e").text("hi"));
```

However when I test the closure compiler on the official demo website: https://closure-compiler.appspot.com/home the < and > characters are not changed.

Is there an option to disable that?

Here is my java code:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.logging.Level;

import com.google.javascript.jscomp.CheckLevel;
import com.google.javascript.jscomp.CompilationLevel;
import com.google.javascript.jscomp.Compiler;
import com.google.javascript.jscomp.CompilerOptions;
import com.google.javascript.jscomp.PropertyRenamingPolicy;
import com.google.javascript.jscomp.SourceFile;
import com.google.javascript.jscomp.VariableRenamingPolicy;
import com.google.javascript.jscomp.WarningLevel;

public class ClosureCompiler {

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        String code = "$('#something').append($('<div></div>').text('hi'));";
        String outputFilename = "a.txt";

        Compiler.setLoggingLevel(Level.OFF);
        Compiler compiler = new Compiler();

        CompilerOptions compilerOptions = new CompilerOptions();
        compilerOptions.checkGlobalThisLevel = CheckLevel.OFF;
        compilerOptions.closurePass = false;
        compilerOptions.coalesceVariableNames = true;
        compilerOptions.collapseVariableDeclarations = true;
        compilerOptions.convertToDottedProperties = true;
        compilerOptions.deadAssignmentElimination = true;
        compilerOptions.flowSensitiveInlineVariables = true;
        compilerOptions.foldConstants = true;
        compilerOptions.labelRenaming = true;
        compilerOptions.removeDeadCode = true;
        compilerOptions.optimizeArgumentsArray = true;

        compilerOptions.setAssumeClosuresOnlyCaptureReferences(false);
        compilerOptions.setInlineFunctions(CompilerOptions.Reach.LOCAL_ONLY);
        compilerOptions.setInlineVariables(CompilerOptions.Reach.LOCAL_ONLY);
        compilerOptions.setRenamingPolicy(VariableRenamingPolicy.LOCAL, PropertyRenamingPolicy.OFF);
        compilerOptions.setRemoveUnusedVariables(CompilerOptions.Reach.LOCAL_ONLY);

        System.out.println(compilerOptions.convertToDottedProperties);

        CompilationLevel.SIMPLE_OPTIMIZATIONS.setOptionsForCompilationLevel(compilerOptions);

        WarningLevel.DEFAULT.setOptionsForWarningLevel(compilerOptions);

        List<SourceFile> primaryJavascriptFiles = new ArrayList<SourceFile>();
        primaryJavascriptFiles.add(SourceFile.fromCode(outputFilename, code));

        compiler.compile(new ArrayList<SourceFile>(), primaryJavascriptFiles, compilerOptions);

        System.out.println(compiler.toSource());



    }

}
```

Thanks

Comment: Output charset? https://github.com/google/closure-compiler/blob/master/src/com/google/javascript/jscomp/CompilerOptions.java#L1674-L1679

Comment: @ChadKillingsworth nope. I put StandardCharsets.UTF_8 and it's the same

Comment: These represent the same character, why is it a problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This option is controlled by `CompilerOptions#setTrustedStrings`.  This defaults to "false" but is set to "true" by the command-line runner.  This option is useful when the compiler is used "on the fly" with uncontrolled inputs where it is possible a malicious agent could inject an script tag giving them control of the page.  That is injecting user data into javascript.  If this is not the case for you setting trusted strings is ok.

Comment: Can this option be set using closure-compiler-npm or could you please share any code snippet to force it to true? I'm having issue when compiler is replacing ```<!-- ko .. -->``` with this which breaks KnockoutJS because it no longer recognizes the HTML comment as a binding directive

Comment: Can you file a bug for this?   I expect it is a issue with JS version options.